# How to convert following text in required format in unix?

Tags: unix, awk

I have a file which has the following format:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I am trying to make it like:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

I have tried

`awk 'BEGIN { ORS= " "} {print}' test.txt`

It makes 1 2  3 4  5 6. But I need to make it in the aforementioned format.
I also tried

```
awk 'BEGIN { ORS= " "} {print}' test.txt | tr '  ' '\n'
```

but it seems `tr` does not consider double whitespaces and the result comes:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

What can I do?

**PS** In the file there is one newline between 1 and 2 and 4 and 5 and so on and two newlines between 2 and 3 and 4 and 5 and so on. Due to limited knowledge in this editor I am not able to print that way.

Comment: use the `{}` tool at top left of edit box for code/data/output. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your file is called `test.txt`, you can do

```
xargs -L 2 < test.txt
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain how is this code working?

Comment: Of course - `xargs` takes whatever it sees on its inputs (called `"stdin"`) and runs whatever command you supply on them. Here I didn't supply a command, so by default, it just echoes/outputs the things it is given. As I put `-L 2` it reads its input 2 lines at a time. Try `seq 1 12 | xargs -L 3`

Answer (score 0):

Deleting first all empty lines, then using N option in GNU sed

```
sed '/^\s*$/d' file | sed 'N; s/\n/ /'
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't mind to use bash, i have an idea in mind:

```
content=`cat your_file`

while [ -n "$content" ]; do
    read a b content <<< $content
    echo $a $b >> target_file
done
```

this code can fold a string by two. notice that quote matters in this snippet.

Comment: Hi thanks for your anser. But actually my organization uses IBM AIX which is using KSH.

Comment: @Mistu4u em... i don't know about ksh, but i think you can interpret the idea here. it basically read two number at once and iterate over.

Answer (score 0):

Or as you posted an `awk` question, here it is in awk

```
 awk '{printf("%s %s", $0, (NR%2) ? "": "\n") }' file
```

**output**

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
```

IHTH

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `pr` for this:

```
$ seq 10 | pr -t -T -a -s" " -2
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of accomplishing this task in unix. Aside from the answers already provided, here are several methods:

Using sed:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' test.txt
```

Using awk:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS' test.txt
```

Using paste:

```
paste -s -d" \n" test.txt
```

**EDIT** -
I've just seen your note about the new lines. None of the above solutions in my answer will work correctly if there are multiple blank new lines in the file. You would first have to remove them using something like the below:

```
grep . test.txt | {solution from above}
```